# Disable deprecation warnings in the Scala REPL

Tags: scala, scala-repl

Is it possible to disable deprecation warnings in the Scala REPL?

E.g. when I type:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toSet()
```

I get a deprecation warning:

```
<console>:12: warning: Adaptation of argument list by inserting () is deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.
        signature: GenSetLike.apply(elem: A): Boolean
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: GenSetLike((): Unit)
       List(1,2,3).toSet()
                        ^
```

Is it somehow possible to disable those warnings?

PS: I know that this is not a good idea for development, just need it for a presentation.

Comment: What `build.sbt`? I'm just using the REPL.

Comment: Yeah you are right!!!

Comment: This can help you may be https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7934

Comment: That was just an example. I just want to deactivate the warnings.

Comment: If you're doing a presentation, consider recording your terminal session with [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/) then editing the lines out — the recordings it generates are plain text and it's easy to delete any text you don't want displayed.

Comment: The warning in this case is that you should should have entered just `List(1,2,3).toSet` (without the empty parentheses). In _Scala_, use of empty parentheses is a convention to denote parameterless functions that have side-effects. Meanwhile, parameterless functions with no parentheses (like most conversion operations) indicates that they do not have side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warnings can be disabled by adding `-nowarn` flag. Example:

```
$ scala -nowarn
```

Then your example will print:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toSet()
res0: Boolean = false

scala>
```

However I don't recommend turning off those warnings (even for presentation). Please have a look at the result type of `List(1,2,3).toSet()`, it's `Boolean` not a `Set[Int]`.